# Random problem with incorrect URL in emails from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a MOSS 2007 standard farm comprised of a WFE, an indexing server, and a SQL 2005 database server. The web app is being served on port 80 (http) to an ISA server where it is SSL'd. I have AAMs to change the URLs from http to https.

My problem is with the emails that are generated by lists within the MOSS farm. The urls inside the emails are random between http:// and https://. I can't find a pattern to figure out what the issue is. The same thing happens from different lists in different sites all over the farm. The majority of the emails sent out are incorrect.

Update: I figured out that the alerts are https://, which is correct, but the email notifications are wrong.

I may be using incorrect syntax, so what i mean by alerts is from a list when you click actions, alert me. And notifications are what gets sent when an item is assigned to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob,

I believe that e-mails are sent with links that use the default zone URL of the associated web applicaiton housing the site collection (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287815.aspx -- see the section called "Configuration requirements of the Default zone").

You said you weren't seeing a pattern in the links.  Are default zones consistent across web applications?  Are you observing something different?

Comment: Currently I have a single web app. The only part that is wrong is the protocol.

Comment: This does seem to be the case. However it only works for lists created after the default was changed. The ones that existed previously still send assignment notifications with the wrong protocol and alerts with the correct protocol.

Comment: Ah, so if I'm understanding correctly ... the default zone was changed after some alerts had been setup?  Since the two tables that contain alert information (in the content database) maintain URL references that are established at alert setup time, this makes sense.  The alerts that were established prior to the change would be broken.  This article may be of use to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/skelley/archive/2007/06/18/alerts.aspx.  It talks about modifying alerts following a web application move; the situation is different, but the outcome matches your scenario.  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The URL that email Alerts from lists will use are stored at the time they are created and use the URL that you were browsing to at that time - it doesn't pick up the URL from a particular zone AFAIK.

(Administrative alerts such as quote ones do, but these are different to list notification alerts)

In your case I believe that because you are using ISA server to do the SSL 'termination' it looks like this :-

SharePoint <=== HTTP ===> ISA <=== HTTPS ===> User

Whilst the user see's HTTPS as far as SharePoint knows its using HTTP and that's the URL that gets assigned to the alert.

skelly's blog article that Sean ref's talks about how to change these URLs using code.

There is also a **updatealert** command added in to STSADM by the Administration Toolkit that can do this - perhaps you can run this (nightly as newly created alerts will be wrong also?) to update any alerts

- [Troubleshooting - The url in Alert
  Email is incorrect](http://sharepointalert.info/2009/10/troubleshooting-url-alert-email-incorrect/)